# Google Calendar Java example

Tags: java, gwt, google-calendar-api

I am new to integration of google apps (APIs). I am trying to integrate google calendar with my Java application using GWT. I have googled for & got many links

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

however I am not able to find end to end example on how to call Google Calendar API from my application with access token generation. I would be great if somebody can guide me this.

thanks in advance,
vijay

Answer (score 0):

Google has a [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java) that can help you with what you intend to developing.

Access Token is generated once the user consented to what the application wants to access and use. OAuth2 deals with this, and usually uses either calendar or calendar.readonly scopes for it.

Actual API usage after that can be done using the client libraries (in your case, [Java client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/)). The [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview) developer page discusses this in detail.

Hopefuly this will steer you to the right direction.